# How to open a popup page that has parameters(calculated in button event) in button event

Tags: .net, asp.net, events, popup, buttonclick

How to open a popup page that has parameters(calculated in button event) in button event

```
ButtonClick()
{
    string id=TextBox.Text;
    /////HERE i want to open a popup as "Index.aspx?ID=id" ///////

}
```

PLESE RESPOND SOON

Comment: do not put *please respond soon* ESPECIALLY IN CAPITAL LETTERS at the end of your post. It will not get you an answer any faster. This is a Q&A site, not a place where you can request teh codez when you get stuckz.

Answer (score 1):

You can't really open a normal popup window from code-behind, you have to do it from the client-side.

So, you can make a Javascript function that opens the window with `window.open`, accepting some parameters, and then use in code-behind `ClientScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock` to make the JS function run after your button click.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bahh2fef.aspx

Comment: i can do like this , but suppose i make a function in java script through method u told ....than how i ll call that method ...????

Comment: suppose JS fucntion a() is created on client side from a server side event .....than how in same event i will call that fucntion of

Comment: @Asad - "than how I'll call that method?" - like I said, with ClientScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock. Check that link I've included, it also has an example of how to use it.